# CMake: How to link a library to an external project

Tags: cmake, gsl

I am new to CMake and I want to build a project (project_a) using cmake in which I have to include an external autotools project (project_b), which in turn I have to link it with the GSL library. This is part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(project_a)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-shadow")

ExternalProject_Add(project_b
SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project_b
CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project_b/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE})

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_B_LIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/project_b-prefix/lib")
set(prefix "lib")
set(suffix ".a")
set(PROJECT_B_LIBRARIES "${PROJECT_B_LIB_DIR}/${prefix}project_b${suffix}")

target_link_libraries(project_a ${GSL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(project_a ${PROJECT_B_LIBRARIES})
```

The problem is that the GSL library works inside project_a, but inside project_b I get "undefined reference" to any GSL function that I try to use.

Comment: I think that `project_b` should detect the library and its headers separately, on its own.

Comment: Can't you use add_library like in https://cmake.org/examples/ ?